# Create Account Using Google Provisioning API

Tags: google-provisioning-api

i am trying to create account using Google Provisioning API  from reseller account.  Let we say the reseller account is : reseller@reseller.com . Before that i already subscribe domain "domain.com"  from Google Reseller API.

Based this link (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#creating_a_user_for_a_domain) i create script like this :

```
package gapps;


import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.AppsForYourDomainException;
import com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.generic.GenericEntry;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level`enter code here`;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import sample.appsforyourdomain.labs.provisioning.ProvisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient;
import sample.appsforyourdomain.labs.provisioning.ProvisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient.UserProperty;


public class Gapps {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Map<UserProperty, String> map = new HashMap<UserProperty, String>() ;
            map.put(ProvisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient.UserProperty.ADMIN ,"isAdmin");

            GenericEntry genericEntry = new GenericEntry();
            ProvisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient provisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient = new ProvisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient("reseller@reseller.com", "*******", "domain.com", "sample-api");
            genericEntry = provisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient.createUser("user", "*******", "fname", "lname", map);
            System.out.println(genericEntry.toString());

        } catch (AppsForYourDomainException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gapps.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gapps.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gapps.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ServiceException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gapps.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

but after try to compile it's always return

> ## You are not authorized to access this API.

I am stuck here. Is there something that i am missed ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is API access enabled for your reseller domain?

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60757

Comment: Hi, i alerady solved this problem. it seems because i using parameter map. When i delete this param, my program worked prefectly.